# Using Phonegap Inappbrowser with a website

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I want to build an phonegap application . Since i'm well versed in asp.net , I wanted to know if i could build the app on MVC mobile platform  and use an inappbrowser using phonegap to link to the website created in asp.net .

If i could , please do mention he drawbacks in doing so .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes you can do this. Phonegap simply uses a large webview and loads local HTML. No reason why it couldn't point to a remote ASP page. However one of the great things about Apps is their offline capability ( speed of loading assets etc )

I would recommend making much of your App work with local stuff and possibly iFraming you remote pages. ( or even better write data services to call remotely with AJAX and render everything via local html )

remember , its an App , you don't want the user to experience "loading" straight away. If possible give them something to use without network and try your best to not make it feel just like a "shelled website"

Comment: Thanks @Lemonsanver .. Could you point me to some architectures/frameworks which could help me do the below you have mentioned : even better write data services to call remotely with AJAX and render everything via local html

Comment: You can't beat jQuery for your AJAX stuff. Sencha & Kendo UI are okay for your front end UI ( as well as some parts of jQuery mobile )

Comment: Also something really easy I made: www.lemonsanver.com/tuxedo